# Dynamically typed languages and remote method invocation

Tags: php, mysql, flash, apache-flex

Some may know that PHP methods can be remotely invoked from Flash.
Sometimes the input parameter of a remote PHP method is an array of integers.
Because PHP is dynamically typed an attacker can pass an array of anything.
The array of integers has to be used in a SQL query.
At the moment I'm preventing injection like this:

```
foreach ($unsafeArray as $value)
    $safeArray[] = (int)$value;
```

What would you recommend? Maybe I should start using Java :D

Comment: The problem is not with the type system, but with the rpc protocol. Static/dynamic typing is orthogonal to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this: `$aSafeArray = array_map('intval', $aUnsafeArray);` to make sure all passed values are an integer.

My advice would be to start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)!
Example:

```
$o->bindParam(':anint', $iInt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What would you recommend?

I'm not a flash expert, but indeed PHP methods could be called just by knowing its name, and the parameters could be passed as array. So the issue is actually not the remote method invocation, but the input filtering and validation.

Depending on the intented behaviour, I would use intval as opposed to hard cast to int (AFAIR it would return 0 on invalid value), otherwise you could throw an exception or whatever. You have to define its behavior first.

> Maybe I should start using Java

No, unless you want a bloated solution both in terms of development speed and huge memory requirement at compile and runtime :p

Comment: For the intended purpose "hard casting to int" and `intval` are exactly the same thing. Also, could you please clarify what you mean by your first paragraph?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I re-read my PHP docs and indeed you're correct. I mean the title doesn't really reflect the real problem, which is input filtering and validation.